# Apexcharts blink when hovering over legend

Tags: javascript, css, charts, apex

When I create a donut chart and populate it with many entries, text in legend gets closer together and therefore the mouseover and mouseout effects happen a lot faster than with less entries. I recorded this behavior - the outcome looks like this:

[Gif sharing: https://gifyu.com/image/aqjj](https://gifyu.com/image/aqjj)

I tried to look at the source code but every change I tried to make broke the code. Is there any simple way to prevent this from happening (while keeping the same hovering functionality)?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and it was due to continuous re-rendering of the chart. Please check if it is not:

- Destroying and create the chart in an event or loop
- Creating multiples charts on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

You're hovering over a load of items without giving it time to show you the one you're hovering over?

Alternatively you can use

```
states: {
    hover: {
      filter: {
        type: 'none',
      },
    },
  },
```